# Wireshark show only packets that haven't been found yet

Tags: filter, wireshark, network-traffic

I'm reading packets with wireshark and most of these packets are repeating multiple times per second (identical). I don't want to see those. They're too many to manually filter (thousands).

So what I'd like is some filter like:
This packet was already captured/displayed, I won't display it again.

Is this possible using wireshark or is any other software (linux) available for this? I definitely need this feature in live capture so doing some magic with a dump file is not an option.

Comment: There are many reasons you may see duplicates. Can you provide an example capture to see how to best address your scenario?

Comment: I'm reading my car's CAN-bus and want to filter out all messages where I don't press any butten. Here's a dump: http://pastebin.com/M7jug1B4